# Water dripping on driver's foot. How to fix it?

Tags: toyota, ac, hvac, water-leak

Just this morning I noticed there is a water dripping into my shoes while driving. My aircon is open. The weather is sunny and warm. My car is Toyota Vios.

[image]

Comment: How much water are we talking about? Is the carpet seriously wet or is it just a tiny but?

Comment: Heater core or heater core plumbing.

Comment: @dlu, 1 drop per 5 seconds at least

Comment: That's more than I would expect from condensation in the outside. I'd lean towards a blocked drain or a leak.

Comment: Looks like the ac drain hose is missing to me.

Answer (score 5):

The air con water outlet pipe might be clogged.

Get it cleaned by a mechanic.

Happened to me some time ago, cleaned the outlet and now everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running the air conditioning the cooling can cause moisture in the air to condense. As mentioned in the other answer most of the condensation should be drained out under the car from the low point in the plenum. If you can find the drain - probably a hose - one thing to do would be to check that the hose is open. I would guess that the drain would come from a corner of the box that the drip is coming from.

Another possibility is that the air conditioning is chilling the ductwork or other parts above your feet. On a humid enough day you could see condensation and drips from that too.

If the drain is open and this is just humid weather condensation you could safely ignore it. I wouldn't expect more than a few drops. But if it is annoying insulating the offending spot should solve the problem. It looks like there is a fastener at the point where it is dripping. A bit of tape or sealant should do it.